# D3 line graph show positive and negative numbers

Tags: d3.js

I'm working with D3 to create a line-graph. This graph is available here [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/npsyvgf5/).

I'm trying to draw lines manually to represent certain data-point-values. I've tried to add comments to most of the lines in the code, so hopefully you can follow along.

My problem is that I cannot seem to draw negative numbers in a good way, if i do, then the graph-data-lines are misaligned. So my question is: How can i scale my graph so that I can show both negative and positive numbers? In this case, the graph *should* go from `2 to -2` based on the max/min values i've set.

currently. I'm scaling my graph like this

```
  //
  // Setup y scale
  //
  var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, max])
    .range([height, 0]);

  //
  // Setup x scale
  //
  var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, dateFn))
    .range([0, width]);
```

In my mind, doing `.domain([-2,max])` would be sufficient, but that seems to make things worse.

Also, my lines do not seem to match what the data-lines are saying. In the jsfiddle, the green line is set at `1`. But the data-lines whose value are `1`, are not on that green line.

So, this is pretty much a scale question i guess.

Visual (picasso-esc) representation of what the graph should look like if it worked.

[image]

[image: graph]

[image]

Comment: if you reduce the height you see that the lines are drawn. Why don't you use the yScale to draw there limit lines? Why not put the limit lines in a array of objects and use a simple forEach to draw all the lines. do you need to see the y-ticks with 10 decimals?

Comment: Do you want to y domain to be [-2, 2] or do you want it to be driven by the data?

Comment: @ksav data-driven, 2,-2 just happens to be what my highest&lowest values are. Shouldve clarified, mb.

Comment: Do you have formulas to work out nominal, upperTolerance, lowerTolerance, innerUpperTolerance, innerLowerTolerance values?

Comment: @ksav they will be processed through a Kettle-job and sent to me through an endpoint, so, they will just appear as inputs for me. i.e. you can consider the tolerance-values to be static values.

Comment: Ok. I've edited my answer below to better align with what i think you're trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you want your y domain to be [-2, 2] as opposed to be driven by the data, you can remove a lot of setup and helper functions from your `drawGraph` function.

After drawing your graph, you can simply loop through the `yLines` array, and draw a line for each with the specified `color`, at the specified `val` according to your yScale.

Update: EDITED: As you will be supplied the values of `nominal, upperTolerance, lowerTolerance, innerUpperTolerance, innerLowerTolerance` from your endpoint (and they don't need to be calculated from the data on the client side), just feed those values into your data-driven yScale to draw the coloured lines.

Below I have just used the values `1, 1.8, -1.8`, but you will receive values that will be more meaningfully tied to your data.

```js
// Setup
const yLines = [{
    val: 1,
    color: 'green'
  },
  {
    val: 1.8,
    color: 'yellow'
  },
  {
    val: -1.8,
    color: 'red'
  }
]

const margin = {
  top: 10,
  right: 80,
  bottom: 60,
  left: 20
};

const strokeWidth = 3;
const pointRadius = 4;
const svgWidth = 600;
const svgHeight = 600;
const width = svgWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
const height = svgHeight - margin.top - margin.bottom;
const stroke = '#2990ea'; // blue
const areaFill = 'rgba(41,144,234,0.1)'; // lighter blue
const format = d3.time.format("%b %e %Y");

const valueFn = function(d) {
  return d.value
};
const dateFn = function(d) {
  return format.parse(d.name)
};

// select the div and append svg to it
const graph = d3.select('#chart').append('svg')
  .attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr('height', height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .style('overflow', 'visible');

const transformGroup = graph.append('g')
  .attr('tranform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.right})`)


// Make a group for yLines
const extraLines = transformGroup.append('g')
  .attr('class', 'extra-lines')



// Generate some dummy data
const getData = function() {
  let JSONData = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    JSONData.push({
      "name": moment().add(i, 'days').format('MMM D YYYY'),
      "value": Math.floor(Math.random() * (Math.floor(Math.random() * 20))) - 10
    })
  }
  return JSONData.slice()
}

const drawGraph = function(data) {

  console.log(data)

  // Setup y scale
  const y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain(d3.extent(data.map((d) => d.value)))
    .range([height, 0]);

  // Setup y axis
  const yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10)
    .tickSize(0, 0, 0)

  // append group & call yAxis
  transformGroup.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + ",0)")
    .call(yAxis);

  // Draw extra coloured lines from yLines array
  extraLines.selectAll('.extra-line')
    .data(yLines)
    .enter()
    .append('line')
    .attr('class', 'extra-line')
    .attr('x1', margin.left)
    .attr('x2', svgWidth - margin.right)
    .attr('stroke', d => d.color)
    .attr('y1', d => y(+d.val))
    .attr('y2', d => y(+d.val))
    .attr('stroke-width', strokeWidth)
    .attr('opacity', 0.5)


  // Setup x scale
  const x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain(d3.extent(data, dateFn))
    .range([0, width])

  // function for filling area under chart
  const area = d3.svg.area()
    .x(d => x(format.parse(d.name)))
    .y0(height)
    .y1(d => y(d.value))

  // function for drawing line
  const line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(d => x(format.parse(d.name)))
    .y(d => y(d.value))

  const lineStart = d3.svg.line()
    .x(d => x(format.parse(d.name)))
    .y(d => y(0))

  // make the line
  transformGroup.append('path')
    .attr('stroke', stroke)
    .attr('stroke-width', strokeWidth)
    .attr('fill', 'none')
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)
    .attr('d', lineStart(data))
    .attr('d', line(data))

  // fill area under the graph
  transformGroup.append("path")
    .datum(data)
    .attr("class", "area")
    .attr('fill', areaFill)
    .attr('transform', `translate(${margin.left}, ${margin.top})`)
    .attr('d', lineStart(data))
    .attr("d", area)
}

drawGraph(getData())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.10.6/moment.min.js"></script>

<div id="chart" style="margin: 0 auto;"></div>
```

Comment: The lines are still miss-aligned from the data. I tried setting one of the yLines to -1 but the data that's on -1 isnt on that line. any ideas?

Comment: attaching image to the question to illustrate @ksav.

Comment: nvm, found it! But not sure how to solve it. i need to set margin.top to 30 in my example. Setting `margin = { top:0.. }`  did the trick, so margin.top is missing from one of the calculations somewhere.

Comment: You're right. `margin.top` was not being added to the transform of the yAxis. Fixed.

Comment: The yLines weren't aligned correctly, see the last sceenshot above. I fixed it, and approved this as the answer. thank you so much for your help!

Comment: Nearly there ;) Have a read of this post https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3019563. Then have a look at the way you are applying margins. This convention suggests to setup your margins once, apply them to a group that holds everything, and then never worry about margins again.